# Printing elements of the tree at level n

Tags: ocaml

A bush is a tree such that a tree node can have either no children, one child, or two
children nodes. Each tree node stores an instance of a type ‘a. The polymorphic type
‘a bush is defined as follows.

```
type 'a bush = 
  None
| One of 'a * 'a bush
| Two of 'a * 'a bush * 'a bush
```

Write a function `print_level : 'a bush -> int -> unit` that prints the keys
of bush nodes from the given level defined with the second parameter.

I have been redoing some of the old problems and stumbled on this. I have no idea how to start.

Comment: It really is just a recursive function that counts each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sold it. Recursively decreasing n until we reach 0 and printing for every element at that level. Trees are really beautiful to work with.

```ml
let rec print_level (tr:'a bush) n =
  match tr with
  | None -> raise Not_found
  | One (v,d) when n = 0 -> print_int v
  | Two (v,l,d) when n = 0 -> print_int v
  | One (v,d) -> print_level d (n-1)
  | Two (v,l,d) -> 
    print_level d (n-1);
    print_level l (n-1);;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how the levels are numbered. Assume for simplicity that they're numbered starting with 0 at the root, and the level of a child is 1 more than the level of its parent.

The simplest might be to think recursively. What if you knew the parameter `n` would always be 0? What would the function look like?

Now assume you want to write your function `print_level` with its parameter `n`. Assume you have a function that works for all level values smaller than `n`. How can you use this other function to solve your problem for level `n`?

Then the big reveal is that this other function is your function itself, calling itself recursively.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer has been posted by the OP, let's look at breaking this problem down. A function to return a list of the children of a `bush` is straightforward.

```
# let children = function
    | None -> []
    | One (_, c) -> [c]
    | Two (_, c, c') -> [c; c'];;
val children : 'a bush -> 'a bush list = <fun>
# Two (3, One (4, None), One (5, None))
  |> children;;
- : int bush list = [One (4, None); One (5, None)]
```

Now, can we recursively run that N times? That's pretty straightforward with recursion.

```
# let children_n n b =
    let rec aux n bs =
      if n = 0 then bs
      else aux (n-1) (List.concat_map children bs)
    in
    aux n [b];;
val children_n : int -> 'a bush -> 'a bush list = <fun>
# Two (3, One (4, None), One (5, One (6, One (7, None))))
  |> children_n 3;;
- : int bush list = [One (7, None)]
```

Now, we need only use `List.filter_map` to map that result to values. Given that you have introduced `None` as a constructor, for clarity I've fully qualified both `Option.Some` and `Option.None`.

```
# Two (3, One (4, None), One (5, One (6, One (7, None))))
  |> children_n 3
  |> List.filter_map
       (function
        | None -> Option.None
        | One (v, _)
        | Two (v, _, _) -> Option.Some v);;
- : int list = [7]
# Two (3, One (4, None), One (5, One (6, One (7, None))))
  |> children_n 2
  |> List.filter_map
       (function
        | None -> Option.None
        | One (v, _)
        | Two (v, _, _) -> Option.Some v);;
- : int list = [6]
```

Applying a print option to these results is simply a matter of applying `List.iter` to that resulting list.

```
# Two (3, One (4, None), One (5, One (6, One (7, None))))
  |> children_n 3
  |> List.filter_map
       (function
        | None -> Option.None
        | One (v, _)
        | Two (v, _, _) -> Option.Some v)
  |> List.iter (Printf.printf "%d\n");;
7
- : unit = ()
```

Here `children_n` has the benefit of being tail-recursive.